# Using SSE encryption of S3 using Terraform! how to specify server side encryption in terraform?

Tags: amazon-s3, encryption, terraform, server-side

i would like to upload few files into s3 bucket via terraform with kms key.The problem is i cannot upload the files because of Properties Server-side-encryption as default: **Do not specify an encryption**
However i can change manual to **Specify an encrption key** and that work!
But i want to get it in terraform!

That should work via terraform!

Comment: Please look up documentation on terraform for s3 bucket resource, and try implementing it by yourself. You can ask question here with code of what you have tried and explaining what problem you are facing..

Comment: Without having the code you are using along with the error and the exact place where it's happening, it's hard to tell.